# JSON to set options in C# application

Tags: c#, json

I need to set/unset configure options for an in-house C# software through its GUI. Can I use JSON?

Thanks

Comment: You want to save your configuration options into JSON format in a file?

Comment: Yes I want to be able to save it in text file and read from it.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I am not sure about your question, but I would recommend to use the built in configuration mechanism of .NET to store user and application settings

https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=.net+configuration

Otherwise use the DataContractJsonSerializer as suggested and do it manually

Answer (score 1):

Sure, you can just use the DataContractJsonSerializer :-)
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412179.aspx